# In Age of Ultron, Thor seems to know something he possibly shouldn't?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

Sorry for the cryptic title, but I realise the film has only just been released in the UK and Europe and is yet to be released in the US.

I'll hide all substantial parts of my question, just in case. I don't want to spoil anything.

> At the end of Age of Ultron, Thor states that 4 infinity stones have now shown up in the last few years.

So,

> By my count we have the Tesseract, from several of the first few films. The Aether, from Thor 2. The Chitauri Scepter, again from several films. And finally, we have The Orb, from Guardians.

Now, to my knowledge

> Thor, and indeed none of the Avengers, should know about The Orb. I don't remember Thor visiting the Collector between GoTG and the AoU. So, how did Thor know that The Orb had appeared? Or is he referencing a different infinity stone?

I'm looking for an in universe answer, ideally.

Comment: I thought it was shown at the end of Thor 2, that the asgardians have relations with the collector so it would make sense they would be aware of the infinity stone from guardians of the galaxy.

Comment: The all seeing Gate Keeper Heimdall might have told him :)

Comment: I remember him seeing all four during his vision.

Comment: I am still confused, isnt guardians happening in a time far away in future. Humans have relocated to a different planet and have met with other aliens. The thing is Thor mentions them being shown up " recently ".

Comment: @dodovah No, *Guardians of the Galaxy* is taking place in the present.  Just in another galaxy.

Comment: @dodovah: humans haven’t relocated to a different planet in *Guardians*. One human* (Peter Quill) was abducted in the 1988 and raised by Yondu (the blue guy). (*And in the film, Quill is actually described as not exactly human...)

Comment: @Keen since their name is Guardians of "the" Galaxy, and they interact regularly (in canon) with the Avengers, I would assume they are still in the Milky Way Galaxy.

Comment: @Kobunite "I don't remember Thor visiting the collector between [movies]" And how do you know what Thor has been up to off-screen?

Comment: @TylerH "Guardians is very much its own thing. They’re not the Guardians of this galaxy; it’s a different one." - [Joss Whedon](http://www.ign.com/articles/2014/08/08/joss-whedon-talks-marvel-and-dc-movies-wraps-on-avengers-age-of-ultron)

Comment: @Keen: although Peter Quill at least originated in our galaxy. If the movie actually is set in a different galaxy, there are means for someone like Yondu to reach earth.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When Thor takes a dip in

> the cave water

we briefly see an image of

> four Infinity Stones

which suggest that Thor sees that too. For all we know, his actual

> vision

contained even more information about the

> Mind Stone/Gem/McGuffin

than we actually see.

Also, in the mid-credits scene of *Thor: The Dark World*

> the Warriors Three take the Aether to the Collector.

Therefore *they* know of the Collector, and thus may well have heard about the events in Guardians of the Galaxy, and passed that knowledge on to Thor. I mean, some big guy blew up the Collector’s home base to steal an orb, and then tried to destroy an entire planet. Word’s gonna get around.

Comment: Thor sees in that Vision and learns that the scepter holds the Mind gem. He also sees the orb(Power Gem). Since he already knows about the other 2, pretty straight forward from there.

Comment: @ash_k29: well sure, he could figure out *which* infinity gemstonemcguffin was in his vision. But he says that four have surfaced recently. We don’t see anything that suggests the vision told him that, although for all we know it might have done.

Comment: Just a small nitpick: the Mind Stone isn't a McGuffin; it's central to the plot of the MCU arc. Maybe you meant to refer to the dip in the pool as the McGuffin?

Comment: Also doesn't GoTG take place *after* Thor: The Dark World?

Comment: @TylerH: “it's central to the plot of the MCU arc” — it is pretty central to Age of Ultron’s plot, I’ll give you that. But the whole MCU arc? That remains to be seen. “Also doesn't GoTG take place after Thor: The Dark World” — yup. I didn’t mean to suggest they heard about events in *Guardians* at the time of the *Dark World* post-credits scene.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Well the whole arc is leading up to a fight with Thanos over all the infinity stones, of which the mind stone is one... so while not *solely* the center, it's equal part of a group of half a dozen things in the center.

Comment: @TylerH: sure, but in relation to the Thanos thing, the gems/stones whatever kind of are McGuffins. They’re not entirely abstract ones (like whatever’s in the briefcase in Pulp Fiction), but they are mysterious, apparently-powerful things for characters to chase so that we can have a story with some fights in it, i.e. McGuffins. (And that’s assuming that the story works out roughly how we expect it to.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Central plot items that appear repeatedly are, pretty much by definition, not McGuffins. Otherwise every plot in every story is just a McGuffin for the author to tell a story. At which point there's no point in applying the term.

Comment: @TylerH: central plot items, sure. I’m arguing that the infinity stones often *aren’t* central to the plot in MCU movies, because you could swap them out with any vaguely-defined item-of-great-power. (I agree that the Mind Stone in *Age of Utron* is more central to the plot than usual, and is thus not a McGuffin.)

Answer (score 6):

> During the film, when Thor speaks of the four Infinity Stones, we can briefly see the four appear on the screen. They do indeed appear to be the four you mentioned. I can not be sure about this, but during the film, Thor left Earth several times in order to 'obtain information he could not get on Earth'. This, in addition to the well where he got the vision of Vision, could have also led him to learn about The Orb. Either this, or him being a god grants him detection over all Infinity Stones, but this seems highly unlikely as the Avengers had issues retrieving all the Infinity Stones.

Comment: The first point seems, as you point out, much more likely.

Comment: In addition, we have to assume that Odin would know of such things.

Comment: @Omegacron You mean Loki (who has taken over as Odin) ?

Comment: @Salmon - no offence, but this has more direct answers in the movie.

Answer (score 3):

We know that Asgardians are some sort of universal protector that are physically based inbetween all other galaxies.  Furthermore we know Thor is a very powerful warrior and leader.  This is demonstrated at the beginning of Thor2:

> ...Thor, alongside warriors Fandral, Volstagg, and Sif, repel marauders on Vanaheim, home of their comrade Hogun; it is the final battle in a war to pacify the Nine Realms following the reconstruction of the Bifröst, the "Rainbow Bridge" between realms, which had been destroyed two years earlier.

As such, it doesn't seem to stretch plausibility much to assume that some rumour of an infinity stone appearing in GotG from reaching his ears - it wasn't exactly being used in a subtle or covert manner.

If anything, it would be implausible to assume otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Thor might got this knowledge from Odin and asgardians also has connection with collector . So the info might came from that side . As far we know as a audience avengers don't know about these stones yet .